# Why does the batches count increase when I access the renderer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, profiler, renderer, batching

I have 81 game objects in my scene. When I play the stats are healthy with 3 batches running. But when I access the renderer in the script the batches count increases for every object. After I accessed all the objects' renderer the situation gets bad.

> Before: Batches: 3 | Saved by batching: 80 | FPS: Nearly 400
>
> After:   Batches: 83 | Saved by batching: 0 | FPS: about 200

Code:     `transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color32.Lerp(start_color, target_color,t);`

I think the question makes sense. "Why did Unity3D did not cost an object a batch before its renderer is accessed? Why is that batch count still  active even after I did my job with the game object?"

---

Updates:
1. Even if I simply access the renderer without changing it, it costs a batch and never it gets decremented.

```
start_color = transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
```

2. I scale the objects by altering the color through lerp. In the inspector, the material gets renamed as mat(instance).
3. I tried using sharedMaterial. Now the batches count is stable as 3 but all the 81 objects change to the same color.
   Story: The 81 can be updated to low, medium, high states with different grey shades. I need to group them categorized when updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you change any properties of a material it will create an instance of the material. This is why your objects aren't saved by batching.

Comment: I need my objects to keep updating between three states. Is it possible to group the objects to use between three sharedmaterials to achieve batch count of 3?

Comment: @DistractionArrestor you can try this trick: Create three materials (for your states) and switch them when it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

@VladislavKurenkov is right. There also is another trick, but it won't work in all scenarios - instead of referencing the material via **GetComponent().material** just make a public variable of type **Material**. Then modify whatever you want on that variable and all the transforms will get affected. Just feed a material from your Assets into the inspector slot. This will save batch.

Comment: @DistractionArrestor I don't believe this is your situation though. If you want individual manipulation of different objects than you should probably follow Vladislav's advice. I posted this so that other developers might find it helpful, or at least a bit informative.